# Contemporary Resources on Cognitive Science of Typing

Tags: language, motor, linguistics, language-processing

[Apologies if this is too general.]

I'm doing research on language production during the computer keyboard typing process. There are some great classic articles like [Rumelhart & Norman, 1982](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364021382800049) and [Salthouse, 1986](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/bul/99/3/303/).

I was curious where more contemporary research is on this phenomena, both from a language and motor perspective.

**Update**:
In response to the comments, here is some clarification:

- I am researching lexical retrieval during typing, as well as the effects of a task's overall cognitive complexity.
- While I am focusing on these aspects, I would like to situate it within the broader context of the typing process. Therefore, any contemporary research of typing, in general, will also be of use.